# an android program using netty gives this error: Could not find class 'javassist.ClassPool'

Tags: java, android, exception, netty

```
Could not find class 'javassist.ClassPool', referenced from method io.netty.util.internal.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.<clinit>
```

I get this error when I try to run my program on android, I didn't have this problem with the plain java program using netty

Comment: You should post the rest of your code, like where you call this class or create the object...

Comment: Netty is an external library I'm using, I don't instantiate neither of these two

Comment: Have you referenced it properly. Are you using eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse, I have added the jar files to the buildpath, there is a problem with netty-android combination. my other project works fine with netty, but that one is plain java program